# Trying to use GmailApp.sendEmail - Getting Missing access token for authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I'm trying to use the `GmailApp.sendEmail()` within an Add-on I'm currently working on, and even though I've given it the necessary scopes, it's still failing to send the message with:

> "Access denied: : Missing access token for authorization. Request:
>   MailboxService.SendMessage."

Added all scopes needed within the project manifest file:

```
 "oauthScopes" : [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata"
    ]
```

.gs file

```
function validateRecipients(e) {
  var toEmails = e.draftMetadata.toRecipients, ccEmails = e.draftMetadata.ccRecipients, bccEmails = e.draftMetadata.bccRecipients, domains = [], uniqueDomains = [];
  var allEmails = toEmails.concat(ccEmails, bccEmails);
  for (var i = 0; i < allEmails.length; i++) {
    domains[i] = allEmails[i].split("@").pop().split(".")[0]; 
  }  
  uniqueDomains = domains.filter(listUnique);
  if(uniqueDomains.length <= 2 && uniqueDomains.indexOf("verasafe") != -1) {
    Logger.log("This Message is Good to Go");
  }

  else if(uniqueDomains.length == 0) {
    Logger.log("This Message has no recipients");
  }

  else {
    Logger.log("Please Validate Receipients of this Message and Try again");
    GmailApp.sendEmail("sherifkd@gmail.com", "Disclosure Alert", "This message might be sent to the following multiple external domains:");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add that one :  `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",`

I think it's where your error is coming from.